# Greene's Theorem On Triangular Region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

$\int_C xy^2\mathrm{d}x + 2x^2y\mathrm{d}y , $
C is the triangle with vertices (0,0), (2,2),(2,4) .

My attempt :
I drew the region
[image: Region given in question]
And I'm taking orientation counterclockwise wise but now I'm not getting how to parametrize the region because I know the equation of OA and OB. But how to solve it...

Please help me.
Thank you !!

Comment: You have had lots of practice setting up and evaluating double integrals. Let's see your efforts here. Edit your post to include what Green's Theorem tells you and description of the region $R$.

Comment: @Doug We do not need to parametrize the boundary curve. We're applying Green's Theorem, right?

Answer (score 1):

$$P=xy^2,~Q=2x^2y$$

$$\partial_xQ-\partial_yP=4xy-2xy=2xy$$

By Green's theorem, the integral equals:

$$I=\int_0^2\int_x^{2x}~2xy~~ dydx$$

You can proceed from here.

Comment: ohh Yeah ! Thank You !! They are just lines $ y = x $ and $ y = 2x $.

Comment: Please try to avoid answering questions which do not meet the quality standards of the site.  For reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/ .

Comment: ok, thank you for telling this @XanderHenderson